# regular expressions (three letters and three numeric)

Tags: regex

i am having a problem creating a regular expression that will validate if the textbox has a three letters in the beginning and three numbers at the end e.g. *AAA999* all 6 are required for this to be valid.

so far i have tried `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]` and `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d{3}`

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Letters are `\pL`; numbers are `\pN`.

Comment: ASP.NET 4 and c# @aioobe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add beginning and end  anchors if you want the textbox to contain only 3 letters and 3 digits.

```
^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$
```

Since you have C# tags, this is how code will look like in C#

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foundMatch = regexObj.IsMatch(subjectString);
```

Comment: i've tried the code version and the isMatch comes back as false when i add tes001 into the textbox

Comment: @ShaileshRama i thought you want capital letters as you kept `A-Z` in your question. If you want small letters also, then use `[A-Za-z]{3}` or use `Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^[a-z]{3}\d{3}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);`

Comment: Thanks alot,

i used the code version because i was going to eventually be posting back on the textbox anyways, thanks for all the help

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Either would work, basically. Depending on how you use it, you might need to specify the start and end of the string:

```
^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$
```

(The validation controls in .NET for example adds the starting and ending matches automatically.)

Comment: i have tried the above expression, but when i type in tes009 it still validates as invalid

Comment: @ShaileshRama: To allow lowercase letters also, use `^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}$`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be unicode compatible, you'd use this one:

```
^\pL{3}\pN{3}$
```